# Explain SBT syntax like compile:compile

Tags: scala, sbt

Although SBT is called simple build tools, it's far from being simple. I still can't get this syntax in sbt session like `compile:compile`? What's the difference between this and just `compile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trick in here is in scopes. If you want really understand how SBT works then always use three commands:

`show <setting>` - Displays the value of the specified setting.
`show <task>` - Evaluates the specified task and display the value returned by the task.

`inspect <key>` - shows info about setting

`inspect tree <key>` - displays `key` and its dependencies in a tree structure.

There are many other good commands, but this will help you most to understand the basics of SBT.

As for the syntax. Each build consists of `settings`, `tasks`, `projects` and `scopes`. There are too much to tell about them, there is a good explanation given on the official [site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html). And the syntax you gave is all about this terms, for example let's take a look at:

```
compile:scalaSource::sourceDirectory
   1         2             3
```

1 - it is a Compile scope 
2 - it is a dependant Setting 
3 - dependency Setting

If you type `inspect scalaSource` you'll see that, if you type just `scalaSource` in the SBT session this will call `scalaSource` in the `compile scope`(`compile:scalaSource`), this explains the difference between `compile:compile` and `compile`, this are the same (call `inspect` on `compile`). The second thing you should take a look at in `inspect scalaSource` is the `Dependencies:` part: `compile:sourceDirectory`, so `scalaSource` depends on the `sourceDirectory` setting in `compile:sourceDirectory` and if you've seen some build on github, in `*.sbt` or `*.scala` build files it's written like:

```
sourceDirectory in (Compile, scalaSource) := ....
```

Just for the exercise, call:

```
show compile:scalaSource::sourceDirectory
```

and you'll see the output like this: `<project-dir>/src/main` and then call:

```
set sourceDirectory in (Compile, scalaSource) <<= baseDirectory(_ / "src" / "sc")
```

and then again:

```
show compile:scalaSource::sourceDirectory
```